# Which sounds more natural?

Tags: verbs

Sentence A: There are two dogs *biting* in the street.

Sentence B: There are two dogs *fighting* in the street.

Which sentence better expresses the intended meaning when I refer to two dogs engaged in an angry fight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could say

> There are two dogs fighting in the street.
>
> There are two dogs biting each other in the street.

But the present participle **biting** alone, intransitively, is not normally used to refer to the canine altercation itself.

Comment: I see. As you explained, it is a problem of transitive and intransitive verbs.

Comment: It is not really a generic "problem".   A zombie might say, if it could talk, *I go around biting all day.*  But when dogs are going at each other, it is idiomatic to say that they are *fighting*.